# How to set relative voltages of a generic NPN transistor to desired values in Proteus 8

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, bjt, proteus

I've been trying to Simulate this circuit from Sadiku's Fundamentals of electronic circuits in Proteus 8. I already did the calculation in the exercise now I want to simulate it with proteus to practice working with transistors.
[image: the circuit I've been trying to simulate]

But the simulated results do not tie in with the calculated values.

[image: Voltmeter readings from the simulation]

I tried changing parameter values like B-E built-in potential, but the results stayed the same.
[image: component editor window]

Here are the current relative voltages which I want to correspond to the values in the text.
[image]

Comment: The simulator is going to be more correct that your hand calculations.

Comment: I got the same values as in the text.

Comment: That doesn't mean the text is accurate. In a simulator, dozens and dozens of parameters are modelled. If you think that grade 1 BJT studies are going to cover all the effects that simulators consider on day 1 you'd be mistaken.

Comment: @ROBINSONCHUKWU The emitter current is about (5-.7)/(10e3+101*200)*101 or about 14 mA. (This means the 0.7 VBE estimate is wrong and more likely closer to 0.76 -- but this doesn't change much so still 14 mA or so.) At 14 mA, 200 Ohms should drop about 2.8 V. So the emitter should be in that vicinity relative to the (-) rail of V1. This also means that about 7 V across the collector resistor or about 12 V - 7 V = 5 V at the BJT collector. What's the question, actually? Do you want the simulator, which takes into account far far more than my napkin and pencil here, to give 4-dig precision match?

Comment: @periblepsis It's not a real circuit I'm designing. I just wanted a very simple generic transistor that acts like what we use in classroom first-year mesh analysis. But from what I'm gathering, this might not be possible

Comment: @ROBINSONCHUKWU Close enough, though. Have a look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/664986/330261) where I show just how close you can get without a simulator when using BJTs in a circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the ideal model in Proteus simulation, although the ideal NPN model has a default forward beta of 100, the V<sub>BE</sub> drop of the transistor model in Proteus doesn't match the one given in the textbook question. Because the textbook assumes the V<sub>BE</sub> = 0.7V for the base current, but Proteus "calculates" using the following equation:

$$
\mathrm{I_S=I_C \ \ e^{-V_{BE}/V_T}}
$$

where I<sub>S</sub> is the transport saturation current, I<sub>C</sub> is the collector current, V<sub>T</sub> is the thermal voltage (voltage developed in p-n junction due to thermic activities), and V<sub>BE</sub> is the b-e drop. The default IS value in the Proteus NPN model is 1E-16 (=1 x 10<sup>-16</sup>) so the V<sub>BE</sub> drop therefore base and collector currents can't match to your hand-calculated values.

In the question, V<sub>BE</sub> = 0.7 V, I<sub>C</sub> = 14.2384 mA (calculated), V<sub>T</sub> (although not used) should be somewhere around 26 mV. With these values, saturation current will be

$$
\mathrm{I_S=14.2384 \ 10^{-3} \ e^{-0.7/0.026}=2.89013 \ 10^{-14}}
$$

Now put **IS=2.89013E-14** in the Edit Properties window (Edit Properties As Text should be ticked, as shown in your question) and try to re-simulate. See if b-e drop is close to 0.7 V.

If still doesn't match then you can try with

- **IS=2.511246E-14** which is calculated using more precise value of the thermal voltage at 300 K, which is 25.865 mV
- or **IS=2.08845E-14** <sup>**(1)**</sup>

<sup>**(1)**</sup> Proteus uses a default temperature of 25°C, IIRC. So it might be using a calculated value of thermal voltage using the \$kT/q\$ instead of a constant value such as 26 mV or 25.865 mV across the whole range. It's 25.69 mV at room temperature (or 298.15 °K). So the IS will be different for this thermal voltage.

Comment: Thank you, sir.

Comment: Wow, it worked!! But to a beginner like me, that seems la bit complicated. Isn't there a simpler component out there for primitive simulations?

Comment: @ROBINSONCHUKWU you can accept my answer if it was useful (apparently it is), by clicking the tick symbol under the points indicator of the answer, so the question doesn't remain open. As for your question, I don't think there's a simpler way because it is what it is – simulators simulate ideal diodes (and b-e junctions of transistors) as per the theory. And this is what we expect.